# Error while connecting Marketing Cloud Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

After clicking on "Connect to Marketing Cloud" in Sales cloud, i am getting the following error. I have cross checked the steps, none is missing.

Error:
Not authorized to use this authentication base URI. Use your authentication base URI found in Marketing Cloud Installed Packages. Do not use exacttargetapis.com.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you need to follow, to resolve this:

1. [Clear configuration](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/07/31/troubleshooting-marketing-cloud-connect/) in MC Connect (great guide by [zuzannamj](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50456/zuzannamj))
2. Add new remote site [as described here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_launch_setup_wizard.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)
3. Reconnect, and map your business units